# How to use results of a mysql query - eg store in another table

Tags: php, sql

I mysql query from a database to return a field which I want to use later.

I can get the query to run and I can print the data from the field using echo to prove the result is as expected
.
I have tried various scripts to store the resultant field as a variable, but no success so far.

Can anyone assist.

Here is the query script -

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['user']); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query) )
{
echo "$row->ID<br />";
```

I now need to store the ID as a variable to test on and possibly store in another table with other data.

I am not a coder and am trying to finish a project for the family which was started by someone else.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I have been trying to get the data into a temporary database and am having an issue.

If I enter this into phpMyadmin it works

```
INSERT INTO tempusertrip (username,ID) SELECT username,ID FROM users WHERE ID=1
```

However if I add it to my php script it does not, and there are no errors in the log file.
I add it like this

```
$query1 = ("INSERT INTO temp2 (username,ID) SELECT username,ID FROM users WHERE ID=1");
```

There is obviously something wrong with my script, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Ideally I need to enter the data where the condition is based on a username contained in a session set previously ($_SESSION['user']) nstead of using 'where ID=1'.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: USE a Select,Insert statement...

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: add die(mysql_error()); to see what happening... mysql_query("Your query") OR die(mysql_error());

Comment: maybe you juste have to select a database to use in PHP before every query ;)...

Comment: @pouki06 - have used the error statement (original effort had syntax error due to non-removal of previous semi-colon). No errors appear on the page or in the error log file - and the database is still not updated with info.

Comment: @user2202256 is the temp table is in the same db ? Else you need to use mysql_select_db ( string $database_name ) before your query...

Another thing, have you checked that you have a row in your select you tried to insert ? ...

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to create a table for your data.  It can be a temporary table that only your connection can see or it can be a regular table (if other connections will need the data).  You'll need to decide what columns you need from the source (if not all) and what extra columns you might need for what you are doing (if any).  Often you just need the primary key from your original table(s) in your new table.  With MySQL if the new table is going to be identical to your old table, use the `CREATE ... LIKE old_tbl_name` syntax for forward-compatibility.

Next (and this is probably what you were looking for in the first place), you'll insert into the new table from a select of the old table:

```
INSERT INTO new_tbl_name SELECT ... FROM old_tbl_name WHERE ...
```

If you have extra columns, you'll need to specify which columns you are copying:

```
INSERT INTO selected_users (username) SELECT username FROM users WHERE ...
```

(The columns do not need to be named the same, but why ask for trouble.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies - sorry I have not responded sooner but my son is in hospital and took a turn for the worse. I have added some info in an edit to my original post.

Comment: Are you calling commit explicitly or relying on auto-commit in your PHP code?